# [Shell Script]Get httpreqest POST in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, post, request

Is it possible to get `POST` data from client side( by ajax) and process it in shell script?

I use jQuery to send data to my server side as

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.cgi",
    type: "post",
    data:{
        test: "123"
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

and I hope I can process the data( as '123' in the sample) in my shell script.

If I use `GET`, I can use `$QUERY_STRING` to get data in my server side,

but I afraid the datas I send to server are too much, so I use `POST` instead.

My server is Linux and my shell script is Bourne Shell( starts with `#!/bin/sh`).

Or is there others method to handle this situation?

Thanks in advanced!.

Edit:

I have web page called test.html, and there is input box, user write '123' in the input box, then click button( not type='submit', just type='button', because I want to use ajax, not use form and let web page load to server side web page), the button will run the ajax in POST to server side cgi--- test.cgi

In test.cgi, I want to get the data that client side POST to it and process it( as save the data '123' to a file.

Comment: its not clear what you need. Can you please say this is the input and this is the output that am expecting and this is what i have tried and not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you use to send the `POST` is completely irrelevant.  If your shell script is invoked as a regular [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) script, the [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) data will be available on standard input.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat >file
```

Perhaps you want to add unwrapping of the [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) container but in essence, the above is all it takes to do what you are asking.

Here's the obligatory caution -- you probably don't *actually* want to use shell script for this.  Please investigate more secure, more robust, more specialized alternatives.